# Can I have two actions for one button?

Tags: php, html

I want to create a form which by pressing the submit button will insert the input to a database and at the same time when the as the site admin I want to get an email notification in my email like " new entry". I can do the first part but I don't have an idea how to notify the admin of the entry via email(Note I do not want the data sent to email, just something to make me aware that someone has submitted the form.

Comment: When someone clicks the button, you can make it do what ever you want. Just add some email code after the database insert. There are _many_ tutorials/guides about sending emails with PHP all over the internet if you do some quick research.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First of all, your question would be easier to read if you check your spelling and insert paragraphs where appropriate. Regarding your question, the button should call a php script (assumed from your tags 'php' and 'html'), and the php script can easily insert a record in the database and inform the admin by mail of this action (without sending the content of the record).

Comment: This is very confusing... When a button is clicked and a form is posted, PHP can do what ever you'd like.. If you're asking if one button can have two different actions independently, then no, two identical requests should not have different outcomes. Try two forms?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, this is helpful. I'm new to PHP and I'm self-learning. I will definitely try this and see. Thanks a lot for the eye opener

Comment: @CodeJunkie Thanks for the info.

Comment: @BogisW. Thank you for pointing out the errors. I overlooked that. and thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course, just define a function() and submit your form data to a function such as handleData(); and in this function, first run your query to submit the data into the database. afterwards, write a statement to send you an email notification.

```
function handleData(){

$sampleData= filter_var($_POST['data'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$query= "INSERT INTO ...";
//execute query

//now send email notification here
mail();

}
```

Comment: That's basically the right approach, but is **very insecure**, as it doesn't filter input parameters (use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php or something similar), and is open for [SQL injection attacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which are very common and easy to perform.

Comment: sure.. sanitizing the input is obvious.. it is just the idea to solve the issue..

Comment: Firstly, it's the author's first posting, and he says, he is a beginner in PHP. More importantly, we never post insecure solutions and assume that everybody just knows about that. Please update your answer so that the code is actually secure.

Answer (score -2):

You can have two actions for one button using JavaScript by assigning a function to your button.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Button text</button>
<script>
function myFunction {
What your function should do. In your case, insert here your code to send the emial. 
}
</script>
```

As for the sending email automatically with a function there are a variety of ways you could achieve this as well, I recommend searching and looking for some articles on how you can send an email on a function.
I would also recommend using server side languages if possible instead of using JavaScript to send emails because if the page source is viewable your credentials and email could be determined easily, try finding an answer using server side languages.

Comment: **Warning!** If you use the code in the first link to send emails (through JavaScript), you've basically given away your email credentials to all visitors, which would be _extremely_ bad. Don't... do.... that! All JavaScript is downloaded to the client (browser), which means that anyone can just read the code and get the credentials in plain text.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that, next time I'll make sure to include in the answer to use some sort of external script so the code source isn't viewable.

Comment: I highly recommend **not sending emails from javascript**. Emails should only be sent from server side.

Comment: Edit your question and remove that suggestion.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to show an easier way to send the emails to give an idea of how you could accomplish something like that. Its a bit easier using javascript than server side languages.

Comment: "Easy" should _never_ be a reason for writing or suggesting insecure code. Security should be by design and always be a priority when writing code. Period.

Comment: Alright, I didn't realize how simple it would be to figure out the email credentials and I did edit the question. I was trying to show an example on how it would be possible so that it would be easy to replicate server-side.

Comment: Please **remove** those links instead of just adding a disclaimer for it! It makes zero sense to recommend something just to warn about it in the next paragraph. It gives very mixed messages and can be confusing for new developers, who might get the impression that it's "kind of ok". The answer still promotes **very dangerous and insecure** practices! It should **never** be used!

Comment: It may not be the best solution and could potentially give away your credentials but the code in the link can be used. There are hundreds of security options available to make it for the code in the links to be secure and not give away credentials. I did remove the link however I disagree where you say the code shouldn't be used. In the right conditions the code could work and wouldn't pose a security threat.

Comment: _"There are hundreds of security options available to make it for the code in the links to be secure and not give away credentials."_ - If the credentials are written in javascript, and javascript uses those credentials, then no, there are no way to make it secure. The javascript needs to be sent to the client in a format that the client can read and parse, which means that anyone that downloads that javascript also can read it. Never put sensitive information in your front end code. Period. But good that you removed those links.

Comment: The front end your your website is accessible to see the code with the view page source, inspect, or a few other methods. There are ways using front end languages to prevent right clicking therefore preventing the user from inspecting the page and the same goes for the page source. For the other scripts that could check the websites code and view the credentials there are a vast number of security scripts that can block users from running these scrips on their web pages. It may not be 100% foolproof, but you can block the vast majority of people from viewing your credentials.

Comment: Preventing right click is not secure _at all_ since you can simply open the browsers dev tools to see the source. Also, all assets (including the javascript is _downloaded to the client_ which means that the browser _literally stores it on the users computer_. Not to be rude, but you don't seem to fully understand how these things works. Instead of arguing, take it to heart when I say: never put sensitive information in javascript. And "not 100% foolproof" means _insecure_. One is one too many. I literally work with infosec and pentesting so I do have _some_ knowledge about this subject.

Comment: Alright, I'll make sure before posting to check if the code is fully secure. I do understand how to assets and code is downloaded to the browser its just usually this information isn't accessible for the average person browsing your website who isn't a web developer. I will however check the code in future answers.